# How to convert string into an integer in shell script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

On bash shell.
I am trying to give variable length of an array in for loop range and print all the elements one by one till last element. My code looks like this

```
for a in {0..$((${#array[@]}))}; do
   echo "${array[$a]}"
done
```

getting below error while executing script

```
line 14: {0..9}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..9}")
```

How to convert length of array into a integer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot make this work! brace expansion happens before variables are expanded

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for a in `eval echo {0..$((${#array[@]}-1))}`
do
  # do stufff with $a like echo ${array[$a]}
done
```

should be fine.. Mind that the count starts from `0` to `total-1` and that is what is done in using
 `$(( ))`.

Comment: Don't you think it is a unsafe practice of recommending to use `eval` when you can just use the arithmetic context operator.? `for ((i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++))`

Comment: both method worked fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @Inian : The use of can be unsafe in certain circumstances, especially when it accepts value from user. But as of here, it is pretty straight forward though a bit unreadable.. But that said `c-style` for loop is the more readable and is recommended.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn’t downvote the answer ;) my emphasis was to not recommend such a practice. Agree using eval is not that dangerous here.